# SQL Performance on DateDiff

Tags: sql-server-2005

How can I improve below sql:

```
dateDiff(d,a.DateValue,Convert(datetime, Convert(char(10), getdate(), 101) , 101))>90
```

It is killing my performance.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

`WHERE a.DateValue > DATEADD(dd, -90, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))`

to make the predicate sargable (wrapping columns in function calls nearly always means an index cannot be used)